# Why does this TCL proc with no args not work?

Tags: arguments, tcl, procedure

This should be an easy one for someone...

I had a function in a TCL script called unwrap.  Modifying it, I realized I no longer needed to pass it args.

So I changed it to

```
unwrap {} {
...
}
```

Now when I call it with no args, i.e.:

```
unwrap
```

I get an error `invalid command unwrap`

Ideas?  How do I properly format a TCL function with no args?

I tried to use this reference, which showed a call identical to mine:
http://users.belgacom.net/bruno.champagne/tcl.html

Is that page incorrect?

FYI, removing the inner code and inserting it into the spot of the call works, so I know its just my syntax, not the function code itself.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You forgot the `proc`

```
proc unwrap {} {
}
```

What probably happened in your interpreter was that you defined `unwrap` with args first, and then when you forgot the `proc` the second time, you didn't get an error b/c the interpreter just thought you were calling `unwrap` itself (instead of redefining it, which is what you wanted).

Comment: calling it with 2 args, to be specific.

Comment: Yep, that worked!  I somehow deleted proc when I was modifying the script.